# How to assign Logical Or operator in varaible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to assign || operator to variable.

```
var status;
if(this.state.selectedStatus === 'ALL'){
 status = 'Working' || 'Left'       #I need this how can we get this      
}else{
  status = this.state.selectedStatus
}
```

#It gives only 'working' output. But I need 'Working' || 'Left'

// For this

```
if(this.state.allEmployees[i].Status === status){
   gEmployees.push({
      value: this.state.allEmployees[i].Name, 
      id: this.state.allEmployees[i].EmployeeId
   })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store an operator for use later, then it needs to be part of a function (and it is the function you store).

To solve this problem, however, just use an array:

```
status = ["Working", "Left"];
```

and make use of the `includes` method to find out if the `Status` matches one of the values in it.

```
if ( status.includes(this.state.allEmployees[i].Status) ) {
```